# Как создать массив объектов класса и обращаться к их методам? C#

Tags: c#

Вопрос такой, есть у меня массив из объектов класса, например, MyClass:

```
MyClass[] arr = new MyClass[5];
```

И вот есть в этом классе метод Info. И мне нужно обратиться к нему через какой-нибудь элемент массива так:

```
arr[0].Info();
```

Но компилятор выдаёт ошибку "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта". И как мне быть? Подскажите, какие варианты обхода этой ошибки есть. Мне нужен именно массив объектов.

Comment: `arr[0] = new MyClass(); arr[0].Info();`

Comment: А точно, спасибо большое.

Comment: создать массив - это как купить гостиницу без жильцов. Место есть, а жильцов нет. Чтобы они там появились, надо их туда поселить. Вот я в примере выше в комнату номер 0 поселил экземпляр класса `MyClass`, а потом уже обратился к нему по номеру комнаты и вызвал метод `Info()`

Comment: Ещё одна проблемка есть. В классе у меня есть свойство, в виде массива:

`public double[] weights { get; set; };`

И когда я обращаюсь к нему вот так:

`arr[0].weights[0] = 3.4;`

Выкидывает ту же самую ошибку.

Comment: `public double[] weights { get; set; } = new double[/*нужное вам количество*/];`

Comment: Компилятор ругается на знак "=" (Недопустимый токен '=' в объявлении члена класса, структуры или интерфейса), и на размер массива (Невозможно указать размер массива в объявлении переменной (попробуйте выполнить инициализацию с помощью «нового» выражения)).

Всё понятно написано, но понять не могу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проьблема с созданием массива рещается так

```
arr[0] = new MyClass(); 
arr[0].Info();
```

создать массив - это как купить гостиницу без жильцов. Место есть, а жильцов нет. Чтобы они там появились, надо их туда поселить. Вот я в примере выше в комнату номер 0 поселил экземпляр класса `MyClass`, а потом уже обратился к нему по номеру комнаты и вызвал метод `Info()`

Проблема с инициализацией поля так

```
public class MyClass
{
    public double[] weights { get; set; } = new double[10];
}
```

Или так

```
public class MyClass
{
    public double[] weights { get; set;}
    public MyClass()
    {
        weights = new double[10];
    }
}
```

Где вместо `10` указываете нужное вам количество.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое, программа работает, что бы без вас делал!

Comment: @АрсенийКривецкий пожалуйста